# Get matched Emp Data from a table using Storedue procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Sql table `tblEMP (EmpID,FirstName, LastName, BranchID, DOB)`.

Now I want to get matches Emp details as following condition:

```
Here F = FirstName, L= LastName, B = BranchID, D = DOB
```

1) Matching :
F == F And
L == L And
B == B And
D == D
2) Probable :
F == F And
L == L And
(S == S or D == D  )
3) Possible :
F != F And
L == L And
(S == S or D == D )

I have Added a filed MatchType and set its value as per Emp detail match.

I have completed this using Dataset comparison but it take more time to compare data.

I have used below code and in dsNameMerge I have all EmpDetail:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsNameMerge.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (i == dsNameMerge.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
      break;
   DataRow dr = dsNameMerge.Tables[0].Rows[i];
   DataRow dr1 = dsNameMerge.Tables[0].Rows[i + 1];
   ... Compare as per above condition and set MatchType and create a   Dataset table and insert matched emp detail with MatchType in it.
}
```

Now I want to do this task using Stored procedure.

How can I do this thing in Stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: I want to get Emp details using grouping as following condition from tblEMP:

1) Matching : F == F And L == L And B == B And D == D
2) Probable : F == F And L == L And (B == B or D == D )
3) Possible : F != F And L == L And (B == B or D == D )

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server? Anyway you can do it with 3 inserts, insert row where condition and row already not in table. To a more precise answer post a more precise question (add tables, sample data, sqlfiddle, etc)

Comment: In short you are trying to find duplicate records or a possible or probable duplicate in a emp table?

Comment: hi ray , you are right. I want to find duplicate records or a possible or probable duplicate in a emp table but using Strored procedure.